# Arduino UNO and ESP8266-01 Wi-Fi cutting out after few seconds

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cjufbgOBYo

My serial output in Arduino editor is this:

```
AT
AT
AT
AT
AT
AT
AT
AT+RST
ATE0
AT+CWMODE=2
AT+CWDHCP=0,1
AT+CWSAP="RemoteXY","12345678",10,4
AT+CIPMODE=0
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSERVER=1,6377
AT+CIPSTO=7
AT
AT
AT
```

The problem is the Wi-Fi is cutting out after a few seconds. I see the network pop up on my phone/on the RemoteXY app and then it disappears after a few seconds.

I have a suspicion it's something to do with the RX needing a voltage divider? But I am just following the tutorial and am new to electronics.

I also haven't wired up an LED yet (I am planning on using a mains relay instead)

All help appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I'll bet one of the small chips on the Uno is getting very very hot, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure, why would that be? Do you know why it's not working?

Comment: It would be getting hot because you're trying to run an ESP8266 from the 3.3V pin of the Arduino. The Arduino cannot supply enough current without the 3.3V regulator overheating. When it overheats it shuts down.

Comment: So do you know how I can rewire it? Any diagrams ?? I guess that tutorial was bad :(

Comment: Get a proper 3.3V voltage regulator that can provide at least 500mA. Run the whole thing off an external 1A (or greater) 5V power supply (phone charger).

Comment: Can I use the 5V pin from the Arduino?

Comment: You can feed your 5V supply into the 5V pin, but you shouldn't try and pull more than a few hundred mA out of it, no.

Comment: no power supply to Uno will allow more current over 3.3 V pin of Uno. the esp8266 resets if it doesn't get the current for peek draw so the regulator doesn't get hot